# How to Change links in node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

i've been trying for a while to get the tabs on my navigation bar to change (including the link) when a user logs in. The whole thing is a problem on the index page, as you should enter it both logged in and not logged in. i have a  in my navigation bar where all tabs are listed via an anchor. This is my app.get of the index:

```
app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
const {userId} = req.session;
if(userId==undefined){
   
res.render('index');

  }
  else{
   res.render('index');
  }
  });
```

and this Is my header :

```
  <nav>
   <div class="logo">Logo</div>
  <div class="openMenu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
    <ul class="mainMenu">
       <li><a href="./">Startseite</a></li>
       <li><a href="./login">Anmelden</a></li>
       <li><a href="./registrieren">Registrieren</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Impressum</a></li>
     </ul>
      <div class="closeMenu"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div>
   </nav>
```

I want to change "Anmelden" to "Log out" with this :

```
    <li><form id="abmelden" method="POST" action="/logout"><a href="./" onclick="abmelden()">Abmelden</a></form></li>
```

And I want to change "Registrieren" to "Dashboard" therefore the link of the a tag and the text must be changed.

Is there a way, where I can use a command like res.send() but to send the  depends on, if the user is logged or not

Comment: One common technique is to dynamically insert a class on the body tag that is either `loggedIn` or `notLoggedIn`.  You can then control the rest of your page purely with CSS.  You just insert both the loggedIn and not loggedIn tabs in your navbar and use CSS so one of them is always hidden based on what class is in the `<body class="loggedIn">` or `<body class="notLoggedIn">` tag.  Then, you use the same page for both, but use CSS to hide/show things based on the state in the `<body>` tag.  You use conditionals in EJS to insert the right class for the `<body>` tag based on the logged in state.

Comment: That sounds very good, but I don't know how to implement it right away. Can you help me?

Comment: I added an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common technique is to dynamically insert a class on the body tag that is either loggedIn or notLoggedIn. You can then control the rest of your page purely with CSS.

You just insert both the loggedIn and not loggedIn tabs in your navbar and use CSS so one of them is always hidden based on what class is in the tag:

```
<body class="loggedIn">
```

or

```
<body class="notLoggedIn">
```

Then, you use the same page for both, but use CSS to hide/show things based on the state in the  tag. You use conditionals in EJS to insert the right class for the  tag based on the logged in state.

You can do this in your index.html page with an EJS conditional to dynamically construct the `<body>` tag with the right class in it:

```
<body 
<% if (loggedIn) { %> 
 class="loggedIn" >
<%} else { %>
 class="loggedOut" >
<% } %>
```

I'm not an expert on EJS so if this isn't perfect EJS syntax, you can hopefully see the concept here.  When you render your template, you need to pass the `loggedIn` boolean to the rendering engine so it can dynamically adjust based on that.

Then, you add CSS that shows or hides:

```
/* hide/show based on login status */
.loggedIn .whenLoggedIn, .loggedOut .whenLoggedOut {display: block;}
.loggedOut .whenLoggedIn, .loggedIn .whenLoggedOut {display: none;}
```

Then, you put both tabs in your navbar and the `class` in the `<body>` tag combined with your CSS will hide/show one of them

```
<nav>
  <div class="logo">Logo</div>
  <div class="openMenu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
    <ul class="mainMenu">
       <li><a href="./">Startseite</a></li>
       <li class="whenLoggedOut"><a href="./login">Anmelden</a></li>
       <li class="whenLoggedIn"><a href="./logout">Ausloggen</a></li>
       <li><a href="./registrieren">Registrieren</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Impressum</a></li>
    </ul>
   <div class="closeMenu"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div>
 </nav>
```

---

Note: You could also use EJS conditionals to just generate the desired tab also so just one tab was generated.  But, the technique shown here creates one EJS conditional and then everything else is just HTML/CSS which some people find to be simpler to manage.  So, you could have multiple places in the page that have loggedIn and notLoggedIn HTML, but they all work off the class/CSS generates from the one EJS conditional.

Answer (score 0):

By "tab" you mean changing the html page title ?

it's done with this (add it in your template) :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>title of the doc</title>
  </head>
  ...
</html>
```

you can add if statements in your template to adapt things.
But it depends of the templating engine you choosed

for twig its done like that :

```
{% if userId %} <h1>im logged as user {{userId}}</h1> {% endif %}
```

dont forget to add userId in the render part like so

```
res.render('index', {userId});
```

Comment: "tabs" mean the navigation bar items within their own HTML.  And the OP has tagged their question with `ejs` so that's probably their templating engine.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you first check if the user is logged in with:
`if(userId==undefined){`

If userID is undefined, that means the user is not logged in, so you send them index.js:
`res.render('index');`

Then you have an else statement for if the user *is* logged in, but in your else statement you send the exact same thing as you did for a non-logged in user:
  `else{ res.render('index'); }`

So if you want a different menu for a logged-in user you probably need to send them different html.

Comment: It's a waste to use completely separate HTML pages for logged in vs not logged in.  Better to use conditionals with one page.

Comment: Agreed. They should really just have separate HTML for the tabs